# Differences in timezone format? Should one format be preferred?

Tags: timezone

Every time I set a timezone format for a server or in PHP I am perplexed at the amount of redundant options, for example:

```
American/Los_Angeles
US/Pacific
Etc/GMT-8
```

These all seem to give the same result. Should one format be preferred over another? Are there any differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`America/Los_Angeles` (not "American") is the preferred IANA time zone identifier for the US Pacific time zone.  You should probably use this one, as it is the canonical "Zone" entry in the time zone database.

`US/Pacific` is an alias for the same time zone.  It is in an older style, from when the time zone database used country names as prefixes instead of larger regions (continents and oceans).  You can continue to use this one if you like, as it is a "Link" in the time zone database which points back to `America/Los_Angeles`.

`Etc/GMT-8` is not correct for the US Pacific time zone.  It is an administrative identifier for a fixed offset of UTC+8.  It does not contain any information about daylight saving time.  Also notice the offset is inverted from the ISO-8601 offsets that we are usually used to.  So `Etc/GMT-8` has a fixed offset of UTC+8.  In general, the `Etc/GMT*` zones should only be used in very specific scenarios, such as for timekeeping aboard ships at sea in international waters.

You might also want to read about the [time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) and refer to [the list of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) on Wikipedia.